# Openshift Online 3 Pro - Collaboration Option

Tags: openshift, redhat

I just purchased on OpenShift Online 3 pro account yesterday.

I want to share Web Console with another member of my team but it doesn't seem to be possible: all my teamates get a "You do not have access to Openshift Online" error message when trying to reach Web Console URL.

FYI:

- I have granted them with the "admin" role in the Resources -> Membership page (try to use both their email address and pseudo)
- All of them use an OpenShift Online 3 Starter account

I fear that they have to purchase an OpenShift Online v3 Pro account to be able to proceed.

Am i right? If no, can you explain me how can I allow them to use the Web Console?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability for people to sign up under a free collaborator account in the Pro tier, with the account only being able to be added against an existing project owned by a paid account isn't quite ready yet. It will be coming in a future update.

A way around the issue for now, presuming that they only need to use the command line, is to provide them with an access token and have them login from the command line using that. That token will expire every 24 hours though and they would need to be provided with a new token by the primary account owner.

Another way is if you can setup web hooks on the projects such that any commits against the Git repository trigger a new build and deployment. That way they don't need to have access to OpenShift itself if working with an existing project.

---

UPDATE

The ability to add non paying collaborators is described in:

- https://blog.openshift.com/add-collaborators-openshift-online-pro-account/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm glad to hear that this feature will be coming soon. Meanwhile, I have been able to generate my token using the following URL: https://api.pro-us-east-1.openshift.com/oauth/token/request.

Comment: Or you can use ``oc whoami -t`` if using the command line. The 'Command Line Tools' page from help dropdown (question mark), will also give you a login command with token that you can use.

Comment: What is the timeline for this?  It is a pain for users upgrading from version 2.

Comment: I don't know of any specific date, but understand it is hoped to be available before the end of the year.

Comment: as of May 10, 2018, OpenShift Online requires the both the admin and the added collaborator to have paid accounts for this to work, although its only mentioned on the support solution for this issue (not the official docs): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3151151

Comment: A collaborator should not need a paid account. See the blog post from December 2017 at https://blog.openshift.com/add-collaborators-openshift-online-pro-account/